# Django template not rendering related model's text

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm currently on the [third part of the official Django polls tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/intro/tutorial03/). Have a problem where when I load the template `detail.html`, `question_text` from the Question model is being rendered fine but `choice_text`(s) are not. The browser shows the correct amount of list bullets as but the text is not there.

#### Here is the template I am trying to load:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
    {% for question in question.choice_set.all %}
        <li> {{choice.choice_text}} </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

#### The associated view function is:

```
def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, "polls/detail.html", {'question': question})
```

#### The models are defined as:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField("date published")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

#### `polls/1` the Question model with two Choices related to it is rendered as

[text from Questions model rendered correctly but elements from Choice model are not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9aOT.png)

---

I expected the related Choice objects obtained from `{% for question in question.choice_set.all %}` to display onto the HTML page as list elements. Instead only the bullets show up without the text.

**Would really appreciate any help!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo, you should assign it to the `choice` variable:

```
<!--     🖟 choice -->
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That was pretty embarrassing... It works as intended now, thank you so much!

Comment: @JEANMAXIMUSCACACHO: relax, we all make mistakes, and often the most "obvious" ones are the hardest to spot.